# Binning Data With Two Timestamps

Tags: timeline, gantt-chart, vega-lite, binning, vega

I'm posting because I have found no content surrounding this topic.

My goal is essentially to produce a time-binned graph that plots some aggregated value. [For Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYZ5A.png). Usually this would be a doddle, since there is a single timestamp for each value, making it relatively straight forward to bin.

However, my problem lies in having two timestamps for each value - a start and an end. Similar to a gantt chart, here is an [example of my plotted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACIjy.png). I essentially want to bin the values (average) for when the timelines exist within said bin (bin boundaries could be where a new/old task starts/ends). [Likeso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVO9F.png).

I'm looking for a basic example or an answer to whether this is even supported, in Vega-Lite. My current working example would yield no benefit to this discussion.

Comment: I have subsequently solved this within the Vega spec (not Vega-Lite), if anyone is interested in the solution just drop a comment or reply and I'll add the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you found a Vega solution, but I think in Vega-Lite what you were looking for was something like the following. You put the start field in "x" and the end field in x2, add bin and type to x and all should work.

```
"encoding": {
  "x": {
    "field": "start_time",
    "bin": { "binned": true },
    "type": "temporal",
    "title": "Time"
  },
  "x2": {
    "field": "end_time"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I lost my old account, but I was the person who posted this. Here is my solution to my question. The value I am aggregating here is the sum of times the timelines for each datapoint is contained within each bin.

1. First you want to use a join aggregate to get the max and min times your data extend to. You could also hardcode this.

   ```
     {
        type: joinaggregate
        fields: [
           startTime
           endTime
        ]
        ops: [
           min
           max
        ]
        as: [
           min
           max
        ]
    }
   ```
2. You want to find a **step** for your bins, you can hard code this later or use a formula and write this into a new field.
3. You want to create two new fields in your data that is a sequence between the max and min, and the other the same sequence offset by your **step**.

   ```
   {
      type: formula
      expr: sequence(datum.min, datum.max, datum.step)
      as: startBin
   }
   {
      type: formula
      expr: sequence(datum.min + datum.step, datum.max + datum.step, datum.step)
      as: endBin
   }
   ```
4. The new fields will be arrays. So if we go ahead and use a flatten transform we will get a row for each data value in each bin.

   ```
    {
      type: flatten
      fields: [
        startBin
        endBin
      ]
    }
   ```
5. You then want to calculate the total time your data spans across each specific bin. In order to do this you will need to round up the start time to the bin start and round down the end time to the bin end. Then taking the difference between the start and end times.

   ```
    {
      type: formula
      expr: if(datum.startTime<datum.startBin, datum.startBin, if(datum.startTime>datum.endBin, datum.endBin, datum.startTime))
      as: startBinTime
    }
    {
      type: formula
      expr: if(datum.endTime<datum.startBin, datum.startBin, if(datum.endTime>datum.endBin, datum.endBin, datum.endTime))
      as: endBinTime
    }
    {
      type: formula
      expr: datum.endBinTime - datum.startBinTime
      as: timeInBin
    }
   ```
6. Finally, you just need to aggregate the data by the bins and sum up these times. Then your data is ready to be plotted.

   ```
    {
      type: aggregate
      groupby: [
        startBin
        endBin
      ]
      fields: [
        timeInBin
      ]
      ops: [
        sum
      ]
      as: [
        timeInBin
      ]
    }
   ```

Although this solution is long, it is relatively easily to implement in the transform section of your data. From my experience this runs fast and just displays how versatile Vega can be. Freedom to visualisations!