# Merge overlapping lines in Vega?

Tags: kibana, vega

I'm pretty new with Vega and sorry if it sounds an stupid question. Let's say I have a data named "my_lines" which is an array of lines where each line contains a start and end points. For example the following could be my "my_lines" data object:

```
[
    {
        start: 0
        end: 10
    },
    {
        start: 4
        end: 12
    },
    {
        start: 3
        end: 11
    },
    {
        start: 16
        end: 25
    },
    {
        start: 20
        end: 27
    },
    {
        start: 29
        end: 35
    }
]
```

now what I'm trying to do is to merge lines with overlapping starting and ending points. for example for the above example I want to transform the data and get the following object:

```
[
    {
        start: 0
        end: 12
    },
    {
        start: 16
        end: 27
    },
    {
        start: 29
        end: 35
    }
]
```

I have searched a lot through the documentation specially transform part but I didn't find a way to transfer the data according to the example I mentioned earlier. any help about this problem would be appreciated.

**NOTE** I'm using Vega inside the Kibana and not java script.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved a very similar problem a while back. If you follow the instructions on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843553/visualization-in-elasticsearch-using-customized-query/68672317#68672317). Once you've completed this you can just filter the data for when the "operation" field is 1 or 0. You'll probably have to do some manipulation afterwards to get it in the form you want, but I do believe its possible just using Vega transforms.

If you are unfamiliar with painless and DSL querying in elastic, I would advise going down the route of using Vega transforms unless your data set is large. Elastic will handle large amounts of data much better than Vega.

If you decide to use elastic to do this instead, I would advise you look into [scripted metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). This is the best way to achieve this. This will require knowledge of the [painless language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/index.html) (java derivative).